# Undirected Graphs

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, a-star

I have an assignment that I'm trying to do using Java, but I am confused about how to set up/what is the nodes for the following graph. Basically, it is the pen plotter problem, or more commonly known as the travelling salesman problem. Where my following input is:

```
Line between 4 1 and 4 4    
Line between 4 4 and 4 7    
Line between 2 6 and 4 4   
Line between 4 4 and 6 2  
Line between 6 6 and 4 4   
Line between 2 2 and 4 4
```

and my output comes out as:

```
<n> nodes explored
cost = 24.61
Move from 0 0 to 2 2
Draw from 2 2 to 4 4
Draw from 4 4 to 6 6
Move from 6 6 to 4 7
Draw from 4 7 to 4 4
Draw from 4 4 to 4 1
Move from 4 1 to 6 2
Draw from 6 2 to 4 4
Draw from 4 4 to 2 6
```

Assuming that the bottom left hand corner of the piece of paper, would be your start (0,0) and it goes up in coordinates, are each coordinate a node, and how would I determine when to move and draw a line. I know I should be using an undirected graph with A* but I'm still quite confused about which ones are nodes (vertices) and how I'd determine when to move and when to draw lines, could someone give me some advice?

EDIT: note that the  refers to the amount/number of nodes explored throughout the whole search.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350371/pen-plotter-problemfind-shortest-path-for-pen-to-move-to-draw-a-diagram-java

Comment: @kgadek, did not see that, not the same person and I'm stuck on a different thing then asking how to do the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use A*, you will first need an [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic). [explanation what it is is attached at the end of this answer].

**Problem as a Graph for A:***

define G=(V,E) as your graph, such that:

`V={all possible drawings prefixes}` [i.e. all possible 'snap-shots' of each possible draw]. note you shouldn't hold this graph in memory, but create it on the fly, with `next()` which will be explained later. [note that practically, for each state you actually need to store only (1)where is the pen currently (2)which lines where already drawn]

`E={all possible changes from one 'snap shot' to another}`

You also need `w:E->R` [a weight function] which will be simply: `w(point1,point2)=euclidian_distance(point1,point2)`

You should also define `next:V->P(V)`: `next(v)={all snap shots you can get from v, using exactly one move/draw`

Finally, you should also define `F`: all "ending" states. `F={all the prefixes which all the lines are drawn}`

**How to run A*:**

start from the snapshot where your pen is at (0,0), and no lines are drawn [this is the initial state], and keep going until you find one of the final states. when you do, if your heuristic is valid, you are guaranteed to have got the optimized solution, because A* is [admissible and optimized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Admissibility_and_optimality)

(*) **admissible heuristic function:** 

let `h*(v)=real distance to target` from vertex v. 

a heuristic function h:V->R is admissible if `h(v)<=h*(v)` for each v in V

**Your real Challenge**

The hard part for TSP is finding a an admissible `h`. It is so hard because you have no idea what's the shortest path is, and if the heuristic function is not admissible, it is not guaranteed that the solution found will be optimized.

**Suggestion:**

You might want to use some [any time algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anytime_algorithm), When I did something similar to this, [solved TSP with multiple agents] I also used A*, but started with a non valid heuristic, and iteratively decreased it, so if I had enough time, I found optimal solution, and if not - I returned the best solution I could find.

Comment: the only graphs I've made consist of a specific point indicated by something like `A` or `B` not by `(1,4)`, how do I create a node for this?

Comment: @SNpn: AStar is working on states graph. A node for A* is a possible state [state == snap shot, as explained in my answer]. each node [=state=snap shot] should contain: (1)which lines are already drawn. (2) where is the pen right now. I'm not sure I understand your question [in the comment] correctly, but I'm hoping this comment helped to clarify some things..

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your answer...also what I meant by my comment, was that usually my graphs I've created are adjacency matrix graphs where theres a table indicating which nodes are connected. EG `A` connected to `B` and `C`. But in this assignment (from OP) I got no idea what how things are connected and how to represent the coordinates as nodes similar to `A`

Comment: @SNpn: in here you should NOT store the whole graph as matrix. my answer addresses this issue: You should develop only the part of the graph that you need, and you store it only in the Open/Closed section of A*. the graph is developed iteratively using your pre-defined `next()` function [I explained about the `next()` function in the last part of "Problem as graph to A*"

Comment: I think I get it...so I should start at `0,0` and look at all the possible points and see which one is the closest, move to it and draw a line to the opposite connecting point, remove it from the list of non-drawn lines and repeat? - but how do I determine which points are possible to get to from one move/draw?

Comment: @SNpn: No, you are now describing a greedy algorithm, which might not be optimal [and might also not be admissible]. You should start from a node indicating no line was drawn, and the pen is on (0,0) and run A* from there, with your admissible heuristic function.

Comment: @SNpn: you can move to every point from each point with one move/draw, your pen can move to every possible point, modifying your so-far-cost accordingly, and if you also drawed, you should also mark this line as being already drawed. You probably should rehearse on how A* works before you are trying to implement it..

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem you are solving is [NP Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), there is no efficient way to tackle the travelling salesman problem. First thing you will have to do is to store all the vertices pair (from and to) in an ArrayList and use them up as needed.

When should you move:
Whenever you are at a point and your ArrayList does not have a starting node in it, you will have to pick the next element in the array and move there.

When should you draw:
A draw can occur in two situations. After you move to certain point a draw will be followed. A draw also occurs when your End point of line segment is present in the ArrayList as a starting point.

After every draw you should remove that particular line segment from the ArrayList. You would be stopping your program when you don't have anything else in your bucket.

Comment: so would it be safe to assume that each node, is just a start/end point for the line?

Comment: A* is exponential time, it is a method of "choosing wisely" which state you want to develop first, using A* will also be exponential time, thus doesn't contradict NP-Hardness, but [with valid heuristic] will find an optimized solution, with less time then brute-force, on the average case.

Comment: @SNpn : Yes, they are a line segment.

Comment: @SNpn, Bragboy: Unless I missed something, this answer is a plain greedy solution for the problem, which does not guarantees optimized solution and does not use A*, as the OP specifically mentioned, or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @amit greedy A* seems right to me, I was reading the specs, and said I had to use A*, so I guess thats what they meant

Comment: @SNpn: There is no problem with A*, but this solution is NOT A*, unless I missed it [and would be glad if you can point me to where]. The graph for A* is always made out of states, and not points. I just don't see how this solution [this answer] gives you optimal path.

Comment: @amit no you didn't miss anything, I'm pretty sure you're correct about this